SQL query gives unexpected NULL results when use 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark' against managed instance
This is the query:
SELECT * 
FROM my_db.sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('my_db.dbo.view_name')

The query will return correct view definition when execute in Azure Data Studio
But when run the query through com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark:
def exec_query(*, query: str, fetch_size: str = _fetch_size):
    return (
        spark.read.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")
        .option("url", _sqlserver_url)
        .option("user", _sqlserver_username)
        .option("password", _sqlserver_pwd)
        .option("query", query)
        .option("fetchsize", fetch_size)
        .load()
    )

It gives wrong results:
+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+
| object_id|definition|uses_ansi_nulls|uses_quoted_identifier|is_schema_bound|uses_database_collation|is_recompiled|null_on_null_input|execute_as_principal_id|uses_native_compilation|inline_type|is_inlineable|
+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+
|1862401804|      NULL|           true|                  true|          false|                  false|        false|             false|                   NULL|                  false|      false|        false|
+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+

It is weird, the object_id is correct, but the definition gives NULL
How can I fix this?

Same login credentials are used for both Azure Data Studio and the script.

i'm guessing it doesn't like nvarchar(max). What happens if you do: cast(definition as nvarchar(4000))

@siggemannen what do u mean, could u pls elaborate how should i do that?

i mean, instead of SELECT *... you do: select cast(definition as nvarchar(4000)) as definition...

@siggemannen just tried, it still gives NULL for the definition

Are you sure that Spark is using exactly the same credentials that you use in Azure Data Studio? sys.sql_modules.definition normally returns null if the object is encrypted but can also do so if the current user doesn't hold ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP or VIEW DEFINITION permissions on the object. Does SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('my_db.dbo.view_name')) return the same result?

@AlwaysLearning sorry, seems indeed it is permission issue, after i switched to use DB system admin credentials, it starts giving correct view definition, could u pls point me out what permission i need to assign to this user?

I assigned the login ##MS_DefinitionReader## server role, then the query gives correct results as expected.
All credit to @AlwaysLearning
